# TightVNC logs 2nd user on as 1st user to Oracle Linux (RHEL)

Tags: vnc, oracle-linux, tightvnc

My coworker and I are working on an Oracle Linux VPS. We use TightVNC to logon to the desktop.

I'm usually logged in first on my own port/session (5901) and when he connects to his (5902) using his own username and password it actually logs him in as me. He has my username in the terminal, my permissions, and we can't both use FireFox at the same time.

Quite odd. How do we make it where he's actually logging in as himself instead of me?

Comment: "use TightVNC" how exactly? in particular how are you staring the respective VNC server session(s)?

Comment: @steeldriver I started it with the `vncserver` command, which created 5901, then when he asked me for a desktop I ran that command again and it opened up the 5902 port. So I take it that's somehow opening more than 1 port but for the same session? Do you know what I should do differently?

Comment: The are different sessions - but they are both yours, since you started both. Your coworker should login and run `vncserver` themself (e.g. via `ssh`).

Comment: @steeldriver oh!! That makes sense. Feel free to add it as an answer.